# Make a background fade in every time "onclick"

Tags: javascript, css, fade

I would like the DIV to show a confirmed message where the css effect "animation" or "fade out" is activated with each click. It works fine on the first click, but not on the clicks that follow.

```js
function clientedetail() {
  document.getElementById("guardadoC").innerHTML = "Guardado.";
  document.getElementById("guardadoC").style.cssText = "animation: background-fade 3s;padding:5px;";
}
```

```css
@keyframes background-fade {
  0% {
    background-color: green;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="clientedetail()"></input>

<div id="guardadoC"></div>
```

Comment: What or where is "fade out"?

Comment: Sure, because once you show it - it's shown, so showing it again won't accomplish anything. You've got to re-hide it in order to be able to re-show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `addEventListener('animationend', function() { ... });` to reset the animation so you can run it again.

It's also a good idea to keep your CSS into your CSS file and not write it as a strings in JavaScript.  Now, we are adding a class to the element to do what we want.

```js
function clientedetail() {
  var el = document.getElementById("guardadoC");
  el.innerHTML = "Guardado.";
  el.classList.add("animating");

  //This function runs when the CSS animation is completed
  var listener = el.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
    el.classList.remove("animating");

    //this removes the listener after it runs so that it doesn't get re-added every time the button is clicked
    el.removeEventListener('animationend', listener);
  });
}
```

```css
@keyframes background-fade {
  0% {
    background-color: green;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: none;
  }
}

#guardadoC {
  padding:5px;
}

#guardadoC.animating {
  animation: background-fade 3s;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="clientedetail()">click me</button>

<div id="guardadoC"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `animationend` event to reset the animation.

> The `animationend` event is fired when a CSS Animation has completed
>   (but not if it aborts before reaching completion, such as if the
>   element becomes invisible or the animation is removed from the
>   element).

You'll notice in this demo that I'm not using anonymous functions. With anonymous functions, we end up redefining the function over and over, which is not what you want regarding performance. Using a functional reference, we declare a function once and tie an event to it.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".myButton");
const guardadoC = document.getElementById("guardadoC");

btn.addEventListener("click", clientedetail);

function clientedetail() {
  guardadoC.innerHTML = "Guardado.";
  guardadoC.style.cssText = "animation: background-fade 3s;padding:5px;";
}

function resetAnimation() {
  guardadoC.innerHTML = "";
  guardadoC.style.cssText = "";
}

guardadoC.addEventListener("animationend", resetAnimation);
```

```css
@keyframes background-fade {
  0% {
    background-color: green;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="myButton">
<div id="guardadoC"></div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8yL2tor/2/)

[More about animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event)

Answer (score 0):

You could recreate the element each time you click the button. This will be a complete reset, and so it will even work when you interrupt the previous animation.

```js
function clientedetail() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("guardadoC");
    var newElem = elem.cloneNode(true);
    elem.parentNode.replaceChild(newElem, elem);
    newElem.innerHTML = "Guardado.";
    newElem.style.cssText = "animation: background-fade 3s;padding:5px;";
}
```

```css
@keyframes background-fade {
  0% {
    background-color: green;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="clientedetail()"></input>

<div id="guardadoC"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigger it based on class if you can, the way you're doing it it will only do it once.

Or you can destroy the element and re-create it kinda like this.

```
function clientedetail() {
    var element =  document.getElementById("guardadoC");
        if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null)
            {
              document.getElementById("guardadoC").remove();
              var remakeDiv = document.createElement("div");
              remakeDiv.setAttribute("id", "guardadoC");
              document.body.appendChild(remakeDiv)
            }

    document.getElementById("guardadoC").innerHTML = "Guardado.";
    document.getElementById("guardadoC").style.cssText = "animation: background-fade 3s;padding:5px;";
}
```